# Is there an Android VOIP solution (such as skype) that can be used as a service from my own activity?

Tags: android, service, sdk, voip, skype

I assume that it is possible to invoke skype or another VOIP solution by starting the appropriate activity. My question is; are there any VOIP solutions that can be used as services in some way, making it possible to write a separate app with its own user interface that just uses the VOIP functionality of the original VOIP app?

[This question](http://developer.skype.com/) is similar, but talks about hooking into the audio streams. Skype has [an SDK](http://developer.skype.com/) but is is currently only aimed at desktop applications.

Comment: Skype isn't based on VOIP ( Voice over Ip), they use a proprietary protocol.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_over_IP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [sipdroid](http://sipdroid.org/)

Answer (score 3):

Android 2.3 supports SIP. The API can be used to make and receive VOIP calls.  See the Android developer site.  There are other solutions for earlier Android OS versions, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007860/looking-for-a-sip-stack-for-android).