# Looking for a SIP Stack for Android

Tags: android, sip

I'm looking for a SIP stack to use on the Android platform. Since it's for a client, to be used for commercial purposes, GPL'ed stacks are not feasible.

What would you recommend, SO?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of Gingerbread, a SIP stack is built right into the API, in the [android.net.sip package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/package-summary.html).

There's some demo code that shows how to use it [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SipDemo/index.html).

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to mark this the answer. Most devices cannot run Gingerbread, and hence do not have access to the API, but till a better solution...

Comment: Also, I just discovered that Verizon turned sip off on my galaxy s3. So this is not a good option for many people.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the JAIN SIP Stack, it should run out of the box. I did try it 1-2 years ago See my blog post with an example about it http://jeanderuelle.blogspot.com/2008/10/jain-sip-is-working-on-top-of-android.html

Answer (score 2):

RADVISION, the company I work for, also offers a SIP stack solution with a commercial license that is suitable for Android: http://www.radvision.com/Products/Developer/VoIP-Developer-Tools/SIP/default.htm
There are other Android related SIP solutions as well, but this is the "general purpose" one.

Answer (score 1):

Alexander Lucas mentioned the Android SIP stack.  There's a review of it here that points out a few missing items: http://www.onsip.com/blog/leo/2011/01/05/our-evaluation-of-android-gingerbreads-native-sip-calling-with-the-nexus-s

A couple of other things to consider are that the phones supplied by carriers may have the SIP stack blocked or crippled, and that the Android SIP stack is not available on the iPhone or other devices.  Many commercial stacks are available ported to Android, iPhone, Symbian, Win7, etc so if you develop for several platforms, your job is easier

Answer (score 0):

I recommend TeleSoft CompactSIP. And I believe in it so much, I chose to sell it.  See http://www.telesoft-intl.com/DS_Android.html

Comment: i'm not sure, but this is rather a spammy link. You've two posts and both are on a SIP Stack you're selling.  Give us some reason it's better than other alternatives at least.

Comment: You missed the part where he says "I chose to sell it"? Personally, I've no problem with people linking to their own work. Lots of people link to other commercial software, so why not link to your own?

Comment: Frank Shearar is right. Hank Karl does run the company Telesoft, so it's not spam, it's just linking to his own work, which happens to be commercial.