# Which SIP Stack choose for closed-source application in Android

Tags: android, sip, jain-sip

I need to make a voice and video calls using SIP. I don't know, which SIP Stack choose, because application must be closed-source, but all quite good stacks are distributed under GPL license. I thinking about using JAIN - SIP stack, but I'm not sure if it is sufficiently
complete and whether it can be
easily implemented in Android. Anybody know a better way? I found this topic ->  [Looking for a SIP Stack for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007860/looking-for-a-sip-stack-for-android) (I don't want use SIP Android API and care about free way)

Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JAIN-SIP is enough for anything. If you find an unsupported use-case let me know and I will fix it.

The SIP stack inside android itself is JAIN-SIP (wrapped in different APIs). JAIN-SIP is at the core of almost all open-source Java SIP phones and servers - Jitsi, Mobicents, JAIN-SLEE uses JAIN-SIP by spec and may be 100s of other projects. No matter what you do you will probably end up using JAIN-SIP behind the scenes anyway :)

Comment: @Vladimir I'm pretty new to JAIN-SIP and can't find any tutorial to make audio/video calls? looking for something that should guide me in the right direction.

Comment: @Vladimir what license does JAIN-SIP use?

Comment: The NIST implementation is public domain. The API lib is under the Oracle's API terms like all other javax.* packages IIRC.